# On slow network previous Ajax request gets cancelled by the subsequent

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have the following problem:
I'm trying to send two Ajax requests almosts simulateously:

```
function ajax()
{
   xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
   {
      if(xhr.readyState == 4)
         console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }
   xhr.open('GET', 'list.html', true);
   xhr.send('');
}
ajax();
ajax();
```

The problem is that only one of them succeeds. 
 And if I try in the DevTools my self, if the network speed is high, they get both executed (when I quickly type the ajax() function twice in the console) while if I lower the network speed and again type them quickly only one of them succeeds.
Why is this happening? How can I avoid this auto canceling of simultaneous xhr requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a local variable to hold the `XMLHttpRequest`. Since you're using a global variable, the callback function always refers to the second AJAX request that was sent. So change:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

to:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Then each callback funtion will be a closure that refers to that specific request that was sent.

Comment: Yes I mistyped, and now it works. But I just simplified the problem, my real problem is that I have an object inside of which there is a method in which I make an xhr request, and  I'm using var xhr, but I get only one executed. What the problem could be there?

Comment: Are the URL parameters the same? Try adding a cache-buster, to prevent the cache from being used.